# Can a wizard use more than one wand?

Tags: harry-potter

Can a wizard use more than one wand at the same time?

Kind of like 2-gun shooting gunfighters in the Old West?

Answer (score 52):

Possibly.

Deathly Hallows was the only mention of something like this:

> He [Harry] leapt over an armchair and **wrestled the three wands from Draco's grip, pointed them at Greyback, and yelled, "Stupefy!"**
>   The werewolf was lifted off his feet by the triple spell, flew up to the ceiling...

Now, it's not clear that he wasn't just holding all 3 wands in the same hand, but it's the only canon example I can find of a wand-wielder having >1 wand at a time.

Comment: Just to be clear - aside from this, there's no discussion anywehere else in canon of simultaneously using multiple wands. So we don't know if its' possible to fire 2 of them independently (different spells or different targets). Presumably, given several Multiple-on-one duels in the books (esp. battle of Hogwarts) if it was possible, JKR would have mentioned it, but that's just conjecture.

Comment: An excellent find. It's clear that force of the spell was far in excess of the usual effect.

Comment: Sounds like it would be, ultimately, more difficult to control

Answer (score 1):

They could, but as most of the work is done by thought, it probably wouldn't do much good. So far as I know of, there are no examples of anyone attempting this in canonical sources.