# Do wizards carry backup wands

Tags: harry-potter

In not-magic world (especially in movies), spies and cops often carry a backup gun in case they are disarmed during combat (the famous gun in the sock).

There are many examples in the books where a wizard or witch is disarmed during combat. All it takes is a simple expelliarmus spell. So it probably would be wise to carry a backup, wouldn't it?

Is there any canon example of a wizard or witch carrying a backup wand?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/can-a-wizard-use-more-than-one-wand and also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81359/what-does-a-wizard-do-if-he-loses-his-wand

Comment: @JasonBaker - The latter is a semi-dupe. Moody uses his walking stick when he loses his wand...

Comment: @Richard Did Moody even carry a wand in the movie? I only remember him using the staff

Comment: @Richard Plus using a random stick or your walking stick as a backup is quite different from carrying a second *wand*.

Comment: @JasonBaker - I'm fairly sure we see him use it in Deathly Hallows/