# Do any wizards carry a backup wand in case it gets disarmed or they want that wand's special benefits?

Tags: harry-potter

Every wizard has a wand, but do any carry a backup in case the first one gets broken or disarmed? I could see that being handy for the element of surprise.

> **Auror:** Expelliarmus! Hah! Now you are harmless without your wand. Looks like it'll be a one-way ticket to Azkaban for y–
>
> **Death Eater:** Avada Kedavra! Whew, that was close! Good thing there's no rule that says I can't have two wands!

I also imagine that a wizard might want multiple wands to use their specialities, like owning both an aspen wand for charms and an ebony wand for transfiguration, since each excel in those types of magic.

Do any wizards carry around a backup wand like this? Let's assume that they aren't just temporarily holding on to their enemy's wands or using them for subterfuge, they own the wands and intend to use they both indefinitely. And the Elder Wand doesn't count either.

Comment: Also: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86341/51379